# remove the click and add it back

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following code and I try to remove the click event and add it back but seem to just remove it.

Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/hL38v50o/

```
$("p").on("click", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").off("click");
});
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").on("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add click only with `$("p").on("click")`. You have to do it like following.

```
function clickFunction () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
}

$("p").on("click", clickFunction);

$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").off("click");
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").on("click", clickFunction);
});
```

**FULL CODE:**

```js
function clickFunction () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
}

$("p").on("click", clickFunction);

$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").off("click");
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").on("click", clickFunction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click this paragraph to change its background color.</p>
<p>Click the button below and then click on this paragraph (the click event is removed).</p>

<button id="btn1">Remove the click event handler</button>
<button id="btn2">Add the click event handler</button>
```

Comment: this seem to work but think like this is just an example and I have a whole function to put inside that so I try something small to just reactivate the onClick functionality

Comment: You can write another function and use it where you adding click function. See updated answer. @MarkusHayner

Comment: Is it working for you? Or I will delete my answer. @MarkusHayner